# Regional differences on an ordinal scale

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ordinal-data

I want to analyse data to see whether three regions differ on certain values. The first value is measured by the item 'Important that government is strong and ensures safety' on an ordinal scale (asking whether the expressions fits with their character):

1   Very much like me
2   Like me
3   Somewhat like me
4   A little like me
5   Not like me
6   Not like me at all

I don't have have to go to deep into the matter, just a first suggestion of whether or not there might be regional differences is sufficient.

The barplot representation of percentage of respondents within one region who respond with a certain response is not very conclusive to me, so I would like to do a significance test:

[image]

However, I can't seem to find the appropriate statistic for this. Would it be wrong to use Cramer's V (which is actually for nominal x nominal), or is this my best option?

Comment: What is your sample size?  If it is sufficiently large--around $1000$ from each region should do--then the differences are strong enough that the choice of test matters little.

Comment: One of the regions only has a sample size of 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I wouldn't use stacked bar charts; William Cleveland, for one, has shown that these are poor representations of data.  I think a dot plot could be a lot better. The help for dotplot, offers this example

```
dotchart(t(VADeaths), xlim = c(0,100),
         main = "Death Rates in Virginia - 1940")
```

You can just substitute proportions for rates, the Likert scale for question of whether they are urban, rural, male, female and the region for the age range.

Next, to answer your question: Your dependent variable is ordinal (how much like me) and your independent variable is nominal (state). So, I suggest ordinal logistic regression. Here you do have a DV and an IV: You are supposing that state influences values, not the other way around.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how a dot plot could allow comparisons of these *proportions* among regions?

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, that does not illustrate the situation here where *proportions of a total* are visually presented. A dotplot in general does not seem designed for such a thing. It could obviously be adapted, by showing *multiple* dots per line--but then it would amount to a graphically crude version of the stacked bar chart! Could you give a more specific reference to Cleveland's criticism of stacked barcharts for this purpose?

Comment: I don't understand what you are objecting to, really. I don't see how the fact that the proportions add to 1 is important to the graphic display. Cleveland objected to stacked bar plots for reasons that have nothing to do with whether the data are proportions: That is, it's hard for people to compare the "stacks" except for the bottom one. Dot plots solve this.

Comment: Cleveland presented a hierarchy of graphical schemata. Although at the top are side-by-side lengths (as metaphors for comparing absolute values), next in the hierarchy are (parallel) lengths that might not share an origin. That is the case with stacked bar charts, so it's not a crippling limitation. Moreover, the SBCs enable ready comparison of *proportions of a whole.* That is not the point of a dot plot, nor do dot plots seem to do that very well. I'm suggesting, therefore, that your (unsolicited) comments about the SBCs may be erroneous and mar an otherwise fine answer to the question.